# SO lacks a mechanism for correcting long-standing false, but popular opinions/beliefs

Tags: discussion

There are cases where false beliefs are widely held, even among expert developers. Social opinion dynamics results in the propagation of such false beliefs and leads to repeated wrong answers on SO, which receive many upvotes. I'd like to point out one such case: the question [Aggregation versus Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-versus-composition), with **the five highest-ranked answers all repeating the same wrong opinion**. I added [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-versus-composition/27889087#27889087) only about six years later, in an attempt to correct all these wrong answers. For getting the attention of the respondents, trying to start discussions with them, I downvoted their wrong answers and left a comment for them.

Instead of considering the issue and discussing it with me or immediately improving their answers, **most of them simply ignored my discussion/elucidation attempt** and one of them even revenge-downvoted my answer. In addition. **SO moderators deleted all my comments**, apparently perceiving my attempt to correct a long-standing false belief as the action of a grumbler.

So, what are the conclusions from this story?

1. An important question about conceptual understanding has been left with all top-ranked answers being wrong.
2. SO moderators didn't promote the disussion of my criticism, but rather oppressed it.
3. SO does not have any mechanism for correcting wrong, but popular opinions. So it will stay with all these wrong answers and continue to promote the underlying false beliefs.

Comment: It might be better to first raise the subject in a relevant chat room. Hone your answer there, making sure it is correct, clear, and well documented before posting it.

Comment: People lack a mechanism for correcting long-standing false but popular opinions/beliefs.  SO is run by people.  It takes a prophet to change people, a job that carries the risk of being ignored or getting nailed to a cross.  The latter outcome more common the louder they are.  SO is not a temple or a soapbox, discussion is strongly avoided, simply state your opinion and convince people with its logic.

Comment: I think voting is the best mechanism to determine which answers are best. It's not perfect, but what would be better? Should moderators or gold tag badge holders be able to promote your answer in some way over the others? I think that would be fraught with difficulty -- what if they also have the wrong view about something?

Comment: Receiving a downvote on your answer may not be a revenge vote. You drew people's attention to your answer, and perhaps when they read it, they disagreed with it?

Comment: Instead of leaving the quality ensurance just to contingent voting, moderators could encourage respondents to reconsider their answers in the light of new criticism and they could invite other experts to join the discussion or provide new answers.

Comment: When the downvote was received as an immediate reaction to criticism, it smells like a revenge.

Comment: Well, your posting a new answer will have brought it to the front page for a while, and your comments will have attracted the attention of the previous posters, so people were given the chance to add or amend. You can't force them to.

Comment: "it smells like a revenge" - but you still cannot be sure, unless someone has owned up.

Comment: I've given up with this issue.  The sheer weight of cargo-cult shit has overcome me.  I cannot fight back.

Comment: But my comments made for catching the attention of the previous posters have been deleted by an eager moderator!

Comment: @gwag What form would that encouragement take? There's a feature request in there (not necessarily a good one). If you are truly suggesting that, you need to flesh out the details.

Comment: @MartinJames Which issue? You don't like the voting system or the aggregation vs. composition issue?

Comment: @gwag: well, maybe Andrew (below) will give you some leeway to leave one comment on each response you disagree with. I do generally dislike identical comments posted across all answers (sometimes I see new users doing this, in an effort to get an answer faster) but perhaps for each you could say something different? Tone matters too, of course.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET 'false beliefs' in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any question that serves as a platform for this drama is, *ipso facto*, 'primarily opinion-based.' Appropriate closure will remove the temptation to attempt to found, or lose, a religion.

Comment: Alright, let's close all questions (and tags) about modeling languages, (data/database/etc.) modeling examples, architecture, design, etc. and keep only questions about well-defined programming languages. But even for the evolution of programming languages (which features should be added to them), people have opinions. So, let's close these questions as well. .

Comment: @gwag Actually; many questions in those tags *are* worthy of closure for just those reasons.

Answer (score 13):

I am the moderator who probably deleted the largest part of your comments on that question, across 5 of the other answers, all basically saying:

> This answer is confusing the main characteristic of composition versus aggregation, which is having exclusive parts and the optional lifecycle dependency between the whole and the part. See my answer below: stackoverflow.com/a/27889087/2795909. –  gwag Jan 11 at 16:11

Try to imagine what this looked like when I came to the post: Most of my browser window was taken up due to the sheer number of comments (There were about ten comments from you flagged across that question, and we get a pop-up interface showing flags on any page which has flags); All of the comments you left said basically the same thing: "Your answer is wrong; read mine instead."

---

There were also a handful of comments on your own answer, where you got rather snippy with a user who questioned your answer, and immediately accused them of "retaliation".

The comment you left instead on January 20 is better. You should have started out like that.

---

Finally, you seem to have a habit of accusing people of retaliating against you with votes. You really should not do that. Trying to guess who down voted you can be fraught with peril. Just don't do it. And even if that user did down vote you, think of it this way:

*You got feedback for the down vote*.

Your reaction is why many people don't comment when they down vote.

Comment: So your prioirity is avoiding/suppressing  objections and disputes, protecting respondents from being disturbed by critical comments, instead of promoting open and controversial discussions?

Comment: @gwag if you can keep it professional, yes. But also, what I saw was that it was you who were 'disturbed' by critical comments. Instead of responding to the details, you accused the user of retaliation.

Comment: @gwag: That's absolutely not what andrew said. I propose you calm down, take a deep breath an re-read it, without trying to find justification for **any** viewpoint. A moderators job is providing the moderation neccessary to keep tempers from constantly boiling over, and removing complete and utter garbage. Trying to uphold either of those answers over the others for their content is not part of his mandate, and would be perilously close to abuse of position (or at least of being accused thereof, which is bad enough).

Answer (score 13):

Regardless of who is right in this scenario, I think your point that "we don't have a mechanism for correct wrong answers" is wrong, we do. Its called *voting*.

You posted your answer on 1/11/15. Its been just *27 days* on a post that had 21K views before now. So expecting your answer, correct/better as it may be to surpass the existing answers in such a short time-frame is unreasonable. Doubly so considering how many people are likely to disagree with you.

If the original poster notices and likes your answer well enough, he can always accept it, which will pin it to the top of the page as well.

As to your conclusions:

1. Perhaps this is true. Even if so, time should balance it out. Even if your post sits at 0 forever, its not really a flaw with the SO model; who's to say **you** are right and everyone else is wrong?
2. A moderator will have to show us the comments, but depending on your tone, they could have been deleted for being "rude or offensive" not because they disagreed with your point. Apparently they were deleted because you were effectively spamming the same comment (see @AndrewBarber's answer).
3. Sure we do, voting/accepting. Just because your answer hasn't risen to the top yet (again, in just *27 days*) does not mean the system is broken.

**Note: This is just my opinion, and isn't related to the above**

At the risk of starting a holy war, I would claim that when discussing modelling, which is simply a way to talk to other people about programming, the general consensus *is* right (no matter what the spec says). The intent is that everybody understands each other. If they do, then life is good.

Comment: Notice that the question is not about (a) modeling (example), but about two concepts defined by the modeling language UML.So your (funny) view is that you want to leave it to popular opinion how the concepts of a formal language are defined? Would you also do this for the concepts of a programming language?

Comment: @gwag My point is that the modelling language UML is just a convenient and consistent way to describe a programs design to a fellow human. If everyone agrees on the semantics of such a language, it following a given specification is relatively unimportant. A programming language must be compiled by a computer, so such distinctions are *very* important.  In other words, this whole thing seems like a "mountain out of a mole hill" kind of situation to me, especially given your rather strong response.

Comment: You don't really mean "if everyone agrees" (since this is never the case), but rather "if a majority agrees". However, a language such as UML is not defined by public opinion, but rather by the experts who develop the language. Btw, UML is not only used for describing program designs.It has a much wider range of applications and user communities.

Comment: @gwag Yes, I mean if the majority agrees. And I'm not saying you are wrong, just that this issue isn't necessarily as big as your posts seem to indicate, and that an answer indicating *what* the majority believes is hugely useful when helping people use that language.